# Fetch API Error - preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api

I am trying to implement fetch api to get resources from our server. I can retrieve the resources using Postman and also by pasting the endpoint into the browser. However when I try to hit the endpoint with fetch api I get the following error:

[image]

When making the call from Postman I get the following results:

[image]

When making the call from the application I get the following:

[image]

I have had to hide to actual endpoints because they are corporate endpoints and I cannot expose them. If that causes an issue please let me know and maybe I can use add more information.

***Request Code:***

```
return fetch(url, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: this._headers()
})
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
})
.then(this._checkStatus)
.then(res => res.json());


_headers(auth) {
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    return headers;
}

_checkStatus(response) {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response;
    } else {
        let error = new Error(response.statusText);
        error.response = response;
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please review your routes for OPTIONS method, have you made OPTIONS verb to 404 purposely

Comment: I just updated the post because I realized I forgot to add the actual code for the call. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Aron can u verify with API developer that is CORS is enabled. It will clear most of the things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It generally happen when you are making cross domain requests.
To fix this, you have to enable CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) on your server https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: So my question is, why does this work in postman if the server is not setup correctly?

Comment: because it's browser which restrict cross domain requests, Postman don't restrict those. Read more about CORS

Comment: Ok thank you. I guess I was assuming postman worked the same way as a browser.

Comment: @crack_iT But why OPTIONS method will return 404?. OPTIONS method is one which validates the the authenticity of client request origin

Comment: @Suresh that depends on server configuration

Comment: @SureshPrajapati because your route obviously doesn't have OPTIONS that's why your getting a 404

Comment: @Darkrum verbs like OPTIONS are not added per route basis. It's added at application level and need to check globally for CORS. Possible that server has not enabled CORS and made such OPTIONS req to 404

Comment: @SureshPrajapati wrong OPTIONS can be allowed per route and one can have CORS allowed for routes without the need for OPTIONS if they pass the data as a query and not in the headers or body